# HQL Subqueries in joins

Tags: hibernate, hql

I have a class Order that contains a set of OrderSection's that itself contains a set of OrderItem's.

In SQL, one can use a SELECT statement in a JOIN clause as done in the following query:

```
SELECT
    o.id,
    o.amount,
    sum(s.quantity*s.price),
    sum(s.quantity*i.price)
FROM
    orders AS o
    JOIN ordersections AS s ON s.order_id=o.id
    JOIN (SELECT section_id, sum(quantity*price) AS price FROM orderitems GROUP BY section_id) AS i ON i.section_id=s.id
GROUP BY o.id, o.amount
```

Would it be possible to express such a query in HQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something, your query can be rewritten in SQL as:

```
SELECT
  o.id,
  o.amount,
  sum(s.quantity*s.price),
  sum(s.quantity*i.quantity*i.price)
FROM orders AS o
  JOIN ordersections AS s ON s.order_id=o.id
  JOIN orderitems AS i ON i.section_id=s.id
GROUP BY o.id, o.amount
```

In which case it can then be rewritten in HQL as:

```
SELECT
  o.id,
  o.amount,
  sum(s.quantity*s.price),
  sum(s.quantity*i.quantity*i.price)
FROM orders AS o
  JOIN o.sections AS s
  JOIN s.items AS i
GROUP BY o.id, o.amount
```

If I am missing something and the above query does not return what you want, you're out of luck with HQL conversion because [Subqueries in HQL can only occur in SELECT or WHERE clauses](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-subqueries). You can, however, map your query as `<sql-query>` - should make no difference at the end.

Comment: This does not give the same results because the third column does not depend on the item and will be repeated as many times as there are items in each section.
Dividing it by count(*) should do the trick though, so thanks for your help.