# Hibernate SQL to HQL

Tags: java, hibernate

Im running into some problems when trying to convert a SQL query into HQL (or Criteria/Restriction). I have the following SQL query:

```
Select count(n), CreatedDate from (
  Select count(serverId) as n, Date(Created) as CreatedDate 
  from mytable 
  group by Date(Created), serverId
) as tbl 
group by CreatedDate;
```

So what is the HQL (or Criteria) equivalent?

Comment: HQL is not the same as the criteria API... which do you mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some SQL queries cannot be directly translated to HSQL but this might help: [HQL Subqueries in joins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1141777/hsql-subqueries)